# Redirect all request to subfolders .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is what I currently have

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

so all requests to non existent files end up on the index.html file. But I only want this to occur for top level requests, e.g. "http://example.com/abc" or "http://example.com/abc/".

for requests like http://example.com/abc/def and http://example.com/abc/def/cge etc. I want to throw a 404 error.

edit: the requested path "/abc/def" could be anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That just needs tweaking your URI matching regex a bit:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/?$ index.html [L]
```